# Is it better for optimization always set function parameters as constant links if possible?

Tags: c++, function, optimization, parameters

I'm learning C++ and I'm wondering about better possibilities to define function parameters.

I know there are a lot of cases where it's obvious but I'm interested how is it in general. For example in this simple case:

```cpp
void UpdateIfGreater(int first, int& second) {
    if (first > second) {
        second = first;
    }
}
// or if I define the first parameter as a constant link it'll be more effective?
void UpdateIfGreater(const int& first, int& second) {
    if (first > second) {
        second = first;
    }
}
```

It will be strange if the second one is more effective since the code is becoming uglier but there is no variable copying.

Comment: Not convinced by the dupe, @πάνταῥεῖ. That's specifically about std::string. It's not the same thing at all.

Comment: That third one's good 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I added some more links. I usually try to find better ones and add additional links.